# wrap-file through a specific route

Tags: clojure, resources, compojure

I am setting up static resources for my compojure app. I need to use `wrap-file` instead of `wrap-resource` since I need the static files to be served from the File System.

I followed this [wiki](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Static-Resources) and configured `wrap-file`

Now I am able to serve my static assets from `http://localhost/static-file.css`

What I want to do is to serve my static assets in a specific context `http://localhost/context/static-file.css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Compojure routes, it is important to remember that any route can be wrapped in middleware, not just the top level collection of routes. With that in mind, we can use Compojure's `context` to mount the file system routes where needed.

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] "Hello World")
  (context "/context" []
           (-> (route/not-found "File Not Found")
               (wrap-file "path-to/static-files")))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> app-routes
      (wrap-defaults site-defaults)))
```

Comment: This works well even when wrap-resources is apply to "/". Life saver!